# IUserRepository, where is the implementation code?

Tags: c#, .net, simple-injector

I'm trying to implement SimpleInjector to use Dependency Injector but the exammple on the website uses IUserRepository interface but there is no info about where it is comming from.

Could help me to know where is the implementation.

```
protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Create the container as usual.
    var container = new Container();

    // Register your types, for instance:
    container.Register<IUserRepository, SqlUserRepository>();
    container.RegisterPerWcfOperation<IUnitOfWork, EfUnitOfWork>();

    // Register the container to the SimpleInjectorServiceHostFactory.
    SimpleInjectorServiceHostFactory.SetContainer(container);
}
```

Comment: I think the comment says it all `// Register your types, for instance:`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As John stated, those are just examples.

Assuming you created your own class and interface:

```
public interface IOrderService
{
    void CancelOrder(int orderId);
}

public class SqlOrderService : IOrderService
{
    public void CancelOrder(int orderId) { /* logic here */ }
}
```

You'd register it similar to their example, like this:

```
container.Register<IOrderService, SqlOrderService>();
```

Later on, when you request an `IOrderService` (such as in the constructor of another class), you'll actually get a concrete `SqlOrderService` instance.

---

So their example:

```
container.Register<IUserRepository, SqlUserRepository>();
```

Would suggest they have a class structure like this:

```
public interface IUserRepository
{
    ...
}

public SqlUserRepository : IUserRepository
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: I'm very unhappy with your example of the `IPerson` interface, since that abstraction and the `Person` implementation contain no logic, just behavior and look like entities. DI libraries are for resolving services, not for resolving entities. You therefore communicate the wrong message. For more information see [this](http://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2010/04/14/injecting-services-into-entities/) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24256061/264697).

Comment: @Steven It's great that an author of the library in question checks on relevant questions on SO. By all means, post an answer that addresses the OP's question and I'll vote for it. I can't "unaccept" this one but we can ping the OP.

Comment: The love is mutual. Do note that I don't disagree with all of your answer, only the first example was an unfortunate pick. You know what, I update your question and +1, for the love of Stackoverflow  :-)

Comment: No no, that's a deserved +1.

Answer (score 1):

The `IUserRepository` is something that you would have created (along with `SqlUserRepository`). They are just showing an example of how their injection works.