# Is possible constructor injection using deserialization?

Tags: c#, serialization, ninject, inversion-of-control, ioc-container

On the following code:

```
var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(MyPOCOType));
using (var reader = XmlReader.Create(fileName))
{
    var pocoInstance = (MyPOCOType)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
}
```

I am using ninject.

The MyPOCOType has an dependency that is passed by constructor injection.

The instance of MyPOCOType is being created by the Deserialize method, so the dependencies are not provided.

There are another way to do that without separate the state from my MyPOCOType and without use [Inject] attribute? (still using Constructor injection)

Comment: What about creating another constructor that accept Xml as one parameter, and then use IocContainer to create instance while passing Xml as Parameter?

Comment: Don't attempt to inject dependencies into data objects:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28715966/entity-framework-object-materialization-and-dependency-injection

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`XmlSerializer` does not support this, and does not have hooks for external construction. So : no, basically.

Comment: @ViniciusGonçalves not really, unless you know of an alternative but feature-complete xml serializer

Comment: A workaround I have used is to use property injection right after deserialization. If you wrap the deserialization step into an abstract factory, you can inject the container into the factory (similar to what you would do in IControllerFactory) and call the BuildUp method (or equivalent) to inject the properties before returning the instance. Not very pretty, but at least it is workable.